# ST_AsText options?

Tags: mysql, gis

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-format-conversion-functions.html#function_st-astext gives the following function definition for `ST_AsText`:

```
ST_AsText(g [, options])
```

It also states the following:

> An optional *options* argument may be given to override the default axis order.

It, however, gives no examples of what to set `options` to.

I tried `ST_AsText(g, 1)` and I got this error:

> Error Code: 3560. The string '1' is not a valid key = value pair in function st_astext.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

On this mysql doc page the introduction section says:

`An optional options argument may be given to override the default axis order. options consists of a list of comma-separated key=value. The only permitted key value is axis-order, with permitted values of lat-long, long-lat and srid-defined (the default).`

So I would try passing `"axis-order=long-lat"`.